# one item out of place in bootstrap responsive grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on an about page that features portraits of four founders. They should appear in one line on large screens and then be in two rows of two on a medium screen. However, when I resize the browser, the final portrait is sent out of alignment to the bottom of the page and I'm not sure why.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Meet Our Collaborators</h1>
            <p>Relay has really good dancers. This is placeholder copy. Our dancers are so great. They have been to all sorts of school and done all sorts of performances.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Our Founders</h2>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 centered">
            <img class="img-founder" src="img/founder1.png">
            <h3>Founder1</h3>
            <p>What does this team member do? Keep it short!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 centered">
            <img class="img-founder" src="img/founder2.png">
            <h3>Founder 2</h3>
            <p>What does this team member do? Keep it short!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 centered">
            <img class="img-founder" src="img/founder3.png">
            <h3>Founder 3</h3>
            <p>What does this team member do? Keep it short!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 centered">
            <img class="img-founder" src="img/founder4.png">
            <h3>Founder 4</h3>
            <p>What does this team member do? Keep it short!</p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /row -->

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

The css for the img-founder class is just the img-responsive class in bootstrap with margin-left and margin-right set to auto and the issue was happening before I made that change.

I tried posting screenshots but I don't have enough reputation. I hope this was enough information to be useful and I appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: It likely has to do with the size of the picture. is founder4.png the same size/ratio as the others?

Comment: Could you possibly reproduce the problem at [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new#)?

Comment: Try using the class `img-responsive`, it will do the most